# Возможно ли определить из какого языка символ? Кодировка известна. Языки любые

Tags: python

Есть некоторая строка из символов в известной кодировке, к примеру в UTF-16.

В ней содержатся некие символы одного или разных языков.

Возможно ли как то определить, какому языку определена часть, из которой взят символ?

К примеру, есть буква `А` (русская) и буква `A` (английская), на вид они одинаковые, но... сами понимаете, это не один символ, это 2 разных символа (достаточно просто включить шрифт, поддерживающий только латиницу и это станет очевидно). А еще где то там бегают A из других языков...

LangDetect пробовал, он на русскую букву А (`detect('А')`) выдает что это `bg`...

Update 1: Нет, на набор букв LangDetect тоже не срабатывает. Только на осмысленные строки, похоже.

Comment: Дай ему больше букв, а лучше слова

Comment: Оно не срабатывает. На мой набор букв (который является японским словом, записанным латиницей, он мне говорит `sw` (Суахили, Африка...) При том если я именно эту строку залью на сайт гугл транслейта - гыТранслейт мне скажет Японский и переведет.

Comment: Ну bg правильно, вообще-то... 

Comment: Это как? Bg это же Болгарский, не? Или я чего то не понимаю? Всю жизнь думал, что в UTF'ах каждому алфавиту присвоены свои номера...

Comment: Файл с блоками символов: https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/Blocks.txt . Если символ принадлежит кириллическому блоку (например 0400..04FF; Cyrillic) вы можете сказать что это один из кириллических языков.

Comment: Открою супер секретную информацию: болгары (а также украинцы, казахи, сербы и т.д.)  используют кириллицу. А ещё татары, якуты, чуваши…

Comment: Ясненько. А тогда так: получить однозначную информацию о том, что это латиница, кириллица или, там, арабская вязь возможно? Хотя бы они - являются *разными* символами?

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйся библиотеками pycld2 или langdetect. Установите pycld2:

```
pip install pycld2
```

Затем через `detect` определите нужный язык:

```
import cld2

text = 'Это текст на русском языке'
isReliable, textBytesFound, details = cld2.detect(text)
print(details[0][1]) # выводит 'ru' - язык русский
```

Comment: Ага, спасибо. Сейчас повожусь с билд тулзами и проверю.

Comment: А если langdetect, можно его заставить вернуть мне, что текст на латинице - это латиница? Потому, что langdetect распознает японский на латинице как Суахили...

Comment: Оно не устанавливается... Я поставил MS Build tools как советовали в интернетах, но разницы нету, оно error'ит